# Using key from parent ngRepeat in child ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-init

Im using ngRepeat to populate some code and I would like to do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in reportsData">{{item.name}}<img src="../assets/img/products/{{item.fileName}}.gif">
<ul rn-carousel class="image" rn-carousel-transition="hexagon" rn-carousel-auto-slide rn-carousel-controls rn-carousel-controls-allow-loop rn-carousel-index="2">
<li ng-repeat="slide in item.fileName">
                        <div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + slide.image + ')'}"  class="bgimage">
                        </div>
                    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

However the item.fileName reference doesn't render to the value. How can I make this type of reference work? I've seen some code related to ng-init on the parent ngRepeat that looks feasible but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: is item.fileName an array?

Comment: No fileName is a key in the reportsData array.

Comment: lets have a look at your item.fileName. Calling ng-repeat on it would infer that its either an object or an array. What is slide supposed to be? if slide is an object and item.fileName matches a property in slide you could say slide[image.fileName] without the second ngRepeat

Comment: That is why it doesn't work.  fileName has to be an object or an array to use ng-repeat that way.

Comment: I have an array for each fileName value already created. I just wanted to use the name value dynamically. @JustinHerter Thanks for putting me in the right direction. Im just going to use a generic array name and make the image paths dynamic.

Comment: @JustinHerter your solution assumes that the fileName key is in the second array, but its in the first. How can I call to it in the second array? image: '../assets/img/products/carousels/'+item.fileName+'/0.gif' gives me an "item is not defined" LInt error and breaks the page.

Comment: Nevermind, i got it. Thanks! Ended up with: <div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(../assets/img/products/carousels/' + item.fileName + '/' + $index + '.gif)'}"  class="bgimage">